# Mongoose how to find with distinct?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to select the user ids of newest messages since the last visit of the user but they must be unique. For example if there are 5 newest messages sended by users 3 and 7 it must return an array with this 2 ids.

I tried to select them with the Mongoose distinct but it returns an empty array. This is my current code, The parameter data is an object with uid = user id and laston = Date of the last time he was online.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    uid: String,
    uidto: String,
    msg: String,
    created: Date
});

var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);

exports.getNewMsgs = function (data, cb) {
    Chat.distinct('uid', {$and: [{uidto: data.uid}, {created: {$gt: data.laston}}]}).exec(function (err, docs) {
        cb(err, docs);
    });
};
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In other words *"What's the problem?"* Is not something people can answer unless you can show some data you expect to match, the actual values you are issuing to the query, and the expected result. Usually the process of producing the "minimal and verifiable example" will actually highlight the problem to you and thus solve the issue itself. It's also very unclear in your question what you actually expect, as `.distinct()` may well actually do something completely different to what you are expecting.

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the message

Comment: Show some actual data and what you would expect to return from it. If the result is empty then the common cause is that there is actually no match for the parameters given. So we need a couple of sample documents. The actual parameters you then expect to match on, and also the result you expect to achieve. It's also still unclear if you understand what `.distinct()` does, but if you showed "expected output" along with the other information then we know if you do or not and can point in the right direction. Simply adding "schema" tells us very little.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of testing I found the problem. The value of data.laston was incorrect so the query didn't work well.